# Count of jquery array not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, count

I have a button with an id of `#file_add_btn`. When clicking this button a file input is appended to my form:

```
<input type="file" class="btn_browse" name="file_uploads[]">
```

I create an array to store the filenames for checking whether the selected file is already selected previously by any previous file inputs.

When I try to alert the count of array `filename_array` it is giving me an error in the console:

> TypeError: filename_array.count is not a function

```
var filename_array = [];       
$(document).on('change', '.btn_browse', function() {
    filename_array.push($(this).val().split('\\').pop());
    alert(filename_array.count($(this).val().split('\\').pop()));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `count()` method on an array. There is a `length` property, but that only gives you the total number of items it holds.

To do what you require you could instead use `indexOf()` to check if the array already holds the value you want to add, like this:

```
var filename_array = [];       
$(document).on('change','.btn_browse', function() {
    var selectedFilename = $(this).val().split('\\').pop();
    if (filename_array.indexOf(selectedFilename) != -1) {
        alert('file already selected');
    } else {
        filename_array.push(selectedFilename);
        alert('file added to array');
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3zpn4ghw/)

Alternatively you could just use a single file input with the `multiple` attribute set so that multiple unique files can be uploaded through a single control, like this:

```
<input type="file" class="btn_browse" name="file_uploads[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: I am not having file with multiple attribute.But I need to use multiple file inputs.When I use this code.its saying file already selected in the first case itself

Comment: No problem :) I added a working example to the answer for you anyway